# Optimization: variables vs constraints

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I have an optimization problem that can be formulated either with $n$ variables and $km$ constraints, or with $ln$ variables and $m$ constraints, for $k,l > 1$. I want to know what formulation would be more appropriate in terms (for instance) of computational time. Motivated by this, I am wondering if there exists a way to identify which approach is better.

> For some specific optimization problem (linear, SDP, conic, etc) and some algorithm (e.g. interior-points), which parameter (variables or constraints)  most compromises the performance of finding the solution?

I know it is not a specific question. Maybe the answer depends on the type of problem and on the algorithm employed to solve it. In my case I have an SDP (semidefinite programing) problem  whose the size of matrices can be reduced with some additional constraints.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How large are $n, k$, and $m$?

Comment: For my specific problem, the minimal values of $n = 50$, $m =  100$, $k = 3$ and $ l = 2$. But the number of variables/equations can be very large.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the solver. Some solvers have heuristics that decide whether to solve the dual problem, in which case the number of constraints and variables swap roles. Even knowing exactly which algorithm is used, the sparsity pattern of your formulation can greatly affect the solution time.